# Html5 audio ios play event

Tags: javascript, html, ios, audio

I am trying to detect when audio starts playing on ios. The problem is that play, playing events fire immediatelly when I press play but audio start playing couple seconds later. I am using ~ 5mb audio file.

Why is there such delay between these evets and audio start, and how can I detect when sound actually starts?

```js
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("play", play, false);
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("playing", playing, false);

function play() {
  var h = document.createElement("H1");
  var t = document.createTextNode('play');
  h.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(h);
}

function playing() {
  var h = document.createElement("H1");
  var t = document.createTextNode('playing');
  h.appendChild(t);
  document.body.appendChild(h);
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls preload="auto">
      <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
```

Here is jsfiddle, you can check on ipad.

https://jsfiddle.net/pmw8fa5e/1/

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not exactly sure what causes the delay on an iOs device I'd recommend a workaround which should work no matter what browser is being used.

Instead of listening for a **play** or **playing** events, listen for the **timeUpdate** event. Inside the callback function simply check if the **.currentTime** property of your audio element is bigger than zero.

```js
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("timeupdate", update, false);
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("play", play, false);
var started = false;
var playPushed = false;
var startTime;

function update() {
  if (playPushed && !started && document.getElementById('audio').currentTime > startTime) {
    started = true;
    var h = document.createElement("H1");
    var t = document.createTextNode('playing');
    h.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(h);
  }
}

function play() {
  playPushed = true;
  startTime = document.getElementById('audio').currentTime;
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls preload="auto">
      <source src="https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_5MG.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    </audio>
```

Comment: Ugly fix, but could work for as media started event, but if you listen for play event constantly (for example to change pause / play icon on your player) then you need to get this event every time.